# VBA User Defined Type not defined error

Tags: vba, excel, adodb

I am trying to write a vba script to run a SQL Select script and import the data into a named range in Excel, below is my code;

```
Option Explicit
Dim cnt As ADODB.Connection
Dim rcrds As ADODB.Recordset

Public Sub Update_Scorecard_2()

Dim ssql As String
Dim myrange As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set cnt = New ADODB.Connection

    cnt.Open "Provider=MSDAORA;Data Source=ODSPRD01;user ID=DWH_ADH;password=mypassword;"

Call runQuery(Range("DATA_DUMP_SQL").Value, Range("DATA_DUMP"))

cnt.Close

End Sub
```

I am getting the error "User Defined Type Not Defined" on the line

```
   Dim cnt As ADODB.Connection
```

I do not see how this type is undefined as that is the line where I am defining it.

What mistake am I making?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the reference to "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects Library" set in your project (Under the [Project > References](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677497(v=vs.85).aspx) menu):

If you do not have this set, the runtime environment doesn't know about the `ADODB` library so it throws a not defined error.